# Web Scraping Returning Empty String

Tags: ruby, web, screen-scraping, mechanize

I wrote some code to return and display the five most recent posts on [this website](http://metarand.com). Yet when I run the code using a `for` loop, an empty string is returned. The code is below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
site  = "http://metarand.com"
page  = agent.get(site)

for i in 1..5
  puts "#{i}) - #{page.search("#boxes :nth-child(i) .clearfix .blog-title")}"
end
```

What is wrong with the code, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I'd just like to say, you should be using `.each` instead of `for` and `in`.

Comment: I agree with @weddingcakes. Using `for` is not idiomatic Ruby. Use `each` instead. `for` can lead to results like you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you need something like:

```
(1..5).each {|i| puts %Q~#{i} - #{page.at("#boxes :nth-child(#{i}) .clearfix .blog-title").text}~  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
agent = Mechanize.new
site  = "http://metarand.com"
agent.get(site) do |page|
  for i in 1..5
    puts %Q~#{i} - #{page.search("#boxes :nth-child(#{i}) .clearfix .blog-title")}~
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake:

```
puts "#{i}) - #{page.search("#boxes :nth-child(i) .clearfix .blog-title")}"
                                              ^^^
```

Should be: `#{i}`